# Is there a better way to format the docker output?

Tags: json, docker

I feel there should be a better way here.

I run the following command to see the layers of an image(`nginx` in this case)

```
docker inspect nginx:latest --format "{{.RootFS.Layers}}"
```

And the output I get looks like this.

```
[sha256:f2cb0ecef392f2a630fa1205b874ab2e2aedf96de04d0b8838e4e728e28142da sha256:71f2244bc14dacf7f73128b4b89b1318f41a9421dffc008c2ba91bb6dc2716f1 sha256:55a77731ed2630d9c092258490b03be3491d5f245fe13a1c6cb4e21babfb15b7]
```

Of course that's an array. That looks worse in the command prompt without appropriate wrapping.

Can that be formatted better?

Tried the following variations (all that I knew) but did not help :(

```
docker inspect nginx:latest --format "{{json .RootFS.Layers}}"  // json
docker inspect nginx:latest --format "table {{.RootFS.Layers}}" // table with double quote
docker inspect nginx:latest --format 'table {{.RootFS.Layers}}' // table with single quote
```

Comment: If it's just for console output/viewing, you could try `--format '{{join .RootFS.Layers "\n"}}' `instead, or add a `println` statement. See [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/).

Comment: Did you check some UI tools like Portainer?

Answer (score 2):

## `jq` for pretty print any `json` output

[`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/) is a lightweight and flexible and powerful command-line JSON processor.

Try `docker inspect nginx:latest | jq -r '.RootFS.Layers'`

[Format command and log output | Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/)

### `join` for pretty print with bare docker

As per [`join`](https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/#join) manual:

> `join` concatenates a list of strings to create a single string. It puts a separator between each element in the list.
>
> ```
> docker inspect --format '{{join .Args " , "}}' container
> ```

So, thx [@char](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11033290/char). Hi suggests this:

```
docker inspect --format '{{join .RootFS.Layers "\n"}}'
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use `jq` filters. But I could solve it by doing `docker inspect nginx:latest --format "{{json .RootFS.Layers}}" | jq`. This way `jq` works only as a formatter.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/110#issuecomment-445184444) comment on **GitHub** (*credits on **SimonHeimberg***), I'd suggest using `Python` for this task. It also works on Mac.

```bash
docker inspect nginx:latest --format "{{json .RootFS.Layers}}" | python -m json.tool
```